# iPhone - Need to replay background sound when it comes to foreground from background

Tags: iphone, ios

My application plays a background music when it launches. It stops when I quit the application. But not playing the music again when I open my application. The application has 2 views and I want to play background sound on only main view. So when the app launches it should play the sound until user quit the app or when the user goes to the second view in the app. The sound should be played again only when the user returns to the main view. Currently, I am calling the sub function which plays the sound in 'viewDidLoad' function. please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this method in your AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

[DidBecomeActive Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidBecomeActive%3a)

Comment: Thanks Antonio for quick reply. But I don't think this will solve my issue. Actually my application has 2 views and I want to play background sound on only main view. So when the app launches it should play the sound until user quit the app or when user goes to second view in the app. The sound should be played again only when the user returns to the main view. Thanks